# Server Configuration for Remote Authentication

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Problem:
I have few systems which run the same version of Ubuntu (i.e. 16.04) on my lab network. Currently all terminals have their own local users. Terminals are not uniquely assigned to a user. So a user can login into any available terminal. The problem is creating new user in each system with same password on each of these terminals.
Required Solution:
I need a way so that I create a user on the server (one of the system/terminal will be assigned if required) and then the users can login any of these systems using that account.

I have tried searching on internet but I couldn't find the technical name for the service I am looking for.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you looking for something as LDAP?

Comment: yes, is there any simple documentation to get started with. The best I could find was [howtoforge](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux_openldap_setup_server_client) but it doesn't explain how to configure on clients

Comment: You only need to to [this](http://www.unixmen.com/configure-linux-clients-to-authenticate-using-openldap/)

Comment: Let me make an answer so you can choose it and we can "close" this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need something such as LDAP in order to create users on a server and then replicate them to your clients. As you already have a server side, you'd only need to follow [this guide](http://www.unixmen.com/configure-linux-clients-to-authenticate-using-openldap/) in order to add clients to your server so they get the new configuration parameters, users, groups, etc.